# delete a file in an uploads directory

Tags: php

I have an image file upload repository: `uploads`:

```
public function addArticle($formData,$files) {
    $articles = $this->articleDao->findAll();
    $events = $this->eventDao->findEvents();

    $file = $files->get('image');
    $target_dir = "public/uploads/";
    $extensions = [  
         'image/jpeg'=>'.jpg',
         'image/png'=>'.png'
      ];
    $imageName = uniqid().$extensions[$file['type']];
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$imageName);

    $this->articleDao->insert($formData->get("id"),$formData->get("title"),$formData->get("content"),'/public/uploads/'.$imageName,$formData->get("legend"));

    header('location: /admin');
    die();
}
```

and I want to delete the image when the article is deleted:

```
public function supprimArticle($id) {
    $supprim = $this->articleDao->delete($id);

    unlink(....);

    header('location: /admin');
    die();
}
```

But I don't know what to put inside the `unlink()`.

Comment: Please post your question in English.

Comment: This is __English__ speaking site.

Comment: why no french ? **[see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370386/create-french-stack-overflow)** ... so if  you want to post here, translate your stuff first (dont forget the title).

Comment: Il faut que tu recupères le nom de l'image associé à ton article et mettre le chemin de l'image à supprimer dans la fonction `unlink()`. Ex: (unlink('\chemin_de_l'image\nom_de_limage')) Si tu poses tes questions en français ici, tu n'auras jamais de réponse sauf de moi. Donc, **English please**.

Comment: thanks Bastien for your answer, i tried with:unlink('public/uploads/.$imageName) , but it's undefined.

Comment: before `unlink('public/uploads/.$imageName)` you should fetch the $imageName from your database.

Comment: @BearNithi I've approved your edit. Just note that you may always remove greetings/thanks/helpme and similar fluff as well. :)